# How to generate help document (or chm) from dotnet comments

Tags: .net, comments

I was reading some technical material of dotnet and then i came to know that there is a way by which we can generate good help document from dotnet comments

Can anyone please help me to know that how to generate help document from comment in dotnet. whether this is microsoft utility or third party component?

Answer (score 1):

you can use nDoc:

[NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/)

the usual good practice is to setup your projects to generate XML files and also, as my suggestion, to set *treat al warnings as errors*; in this way your code will be cleaner and no errors and no warnings allowed and you will be notified at compile time if any public method or property or class does not have the XML comment.

After that NDoc does all the job for you ;-)

Comment: Thanks Davide, just want to confirm whether this is free or paid.

Comment: open source as stated in the web site. there are surely many other tools free or paid, search for some alternatives if you are not convinced about ndoc. eg. http://www.naturaldocs.org/

Comment: Hey Davide, Thanks, i have seen NDoc information in website, its free, and as you mentioned this is Best tools among all other(s),